# Determine type of GKTurnBasedMatch

Tags: game-center, gkturnbasedmatch, gkmatchmaker

I want to know if a certain Game Center turn based match was started as an auto-matching match, or if the player were invited by a friend.

I've tried to figure out a way to see that from the GKTurnBasedMatch object itself, but I guess that's not possible. I've not even came up with any reasonable hack. :)

I can of cause store this in the data section of the match, but I want to use this info in a table with many matches, and it is a bit overkill to load the many kB data (and wait for the data load callback) for each match before this one bit info can be used.

One alternative is of cause to store this info on file locally, and maybe I have to do that, but it feels a bit error prone wrt inconsistencies etc.

Does anyone have a nice solution?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by saving an array containing IDs of all auto-matches locally on the device. I'm not particularly satisfied with that solution :)